# displaying values from entry boxes in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently doing gcse computer science and for my current piece of work I have to make a population model. I have made several entry boxes and want to be able to store and then get that information to print on another window and later use it in calculations. Please could somebody help me to get the values to print? I have tried multiple ways without much luck. I apologise, some of the other code i have done may not be right! When i try to run my program, an error saying 'Question 1 is not defined' in the code I have at the minute to try and get the information to print appears.

```
# import the tkinter module
import tkinter


def quitfile ():
    window.destroy()


def setvalues():

    # create a new window
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    # add a title
    window.title("Population Model")
    # make the size of the window
    window.geometry("600x600")
    # set the background of the window
    window.configure(background = "#FFFFFF")

     # title
    lbQuestion = tkinter.Label(window, text = "SET GENERATION 0 VALUES", fg = "#5855FA", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 12 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion.place(x = 10, y = 10)

    #########################
    # question widgets
    #########################

    # question 1
    lbQuestion1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the population number of juveniles?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion1.place(x = 10, y =60)

    # create an entry widget for question 1
    entQuestion1 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion1.place (x = 10, y = 80)

    # question 2
    lbQuestion2 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the population number of adults?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion2.place(x = 10, y =110)

    # create an entry widget for question 2
    entQuestion2 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion2.place (x = 10, y = 130)

    # question 3
    lbQuestion3 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the population number of seniles?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion3.place(x = 10, y =160)

    # create an entry widget for question 3
    entQuestion3 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion3.place (x = 10, y = 180)

    # question 4
    lbQuestion4 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the survival rate for juveniles?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion4.place(x = 10, y =210)

    # create an entry widget for question 4
    entQuestion4 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion4.place (x = 10, y = 230)

    # question 5
    lbQuestion5 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the survival rate for adults?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion5.place(x = 10, y =260)

    # create an entry widget for question 5
    entQuestion5 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion5.place (x = 10, y = 280)

    # question 6
    lbQuestion6 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the survival rate for seniles?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion6.place(x = 10, y =310)

    # create an entry widget for question 6
    entQuestion6 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion6.place (x = 10, y = 330)

    # question 7
    lbQuestion7 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the birth rate?", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion7.place(x = 10, y =360)

    # create an entry widget for question 7
    entQuestion7 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion7.place (x = 10, y = 380)

    # question 8
    lbQuestion8 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the number of new generations to model? (should be between 5 and 25)", fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF" , font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion8.place(x = 10, y =410)

    # create an entry widget for question 8
    entQuestion8 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    # place the widget into the window
    entQuestion8.place (x = 10, y = 430)

    ##########################
    # checking widgets
    ##########################

    # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 1 ###############
    logBtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value", command = entQuestion1.get(),font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn.place (x = 350, y = 60) 

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck.place(x = 350, y = 80)



    # create a button widget to check answers ############# QUESTION 2 ###############
    logBtn1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value",command = entQuestion2.get(), font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn1.place(x = 350, y = 110)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck1 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck1.place(x = 350, y = 130)

    # create a button widget to check answers ############# QUESTION 3 ##############
    logBtn2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value", command = entQuestion3.get(), font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn2.place(x = 350, y = 160)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck2 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck2.place(x = 350, y = 180)

    # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 4 ###############
    logBtn3 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value", font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn3.place(x = 350, y = 210)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck3 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck3.place(x = 350, y = 230)

    # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 5 ###############
    logBtn4 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value", command = entQuestion5.get(), font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn4.place(x = 350, y = 260)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck4 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck4.place(x = 350, y = 280)

    # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 6 ###############
    logBtn5 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value", command = entQuestion6.get(), font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn5.place(x = 350, y = 310)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck5 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck5.place(x = 350, y = 330)

    # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 7 ###############
    logBtn6 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value",  command = entQuestion7.get(), font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn6.place(x = 350, y = 360)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck6 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck6.place(x = 350, y = 380)

    # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 8 ###############
    logBtn7 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Set Value", command = entQuestion8.get(), font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window
    logBtn7.place(x = 540, y = 410)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck7 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbCheck7.place(x = 540, y = 410)

    # create a button widget to return to main menu
    logBtn8 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Main Menu", font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window # 250
    logBtn8.place(x = 180, y = 560)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck8 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window # 200
    lbCheck8.place(x = 180, y = 560)

    # create a button widget to display generation 0 values
    logBtn9 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Display Generation 0 values", command = displayvalues,  font = "verdana 8 bold" )
    # place the widget in the window # 250
    logBtn9.place(x = 270, y = 560)

    # create a check answers label
    lbCheck9 = tkinter.Label(window, fg = "#000000", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 8 bold")
    # place the widget into the window #200
    lbCheck9.place(x = 270, y = 560)

    Question1 = entQuestion1.get()
    Question2 = entQuestion2.get()
    Question3 = entQuestion3.get()
    Question4 = entQuestion4.get()
    Question5 = entQuestion5.get()
    Question6 = entQuestion6.get()
    Question7 = entQuestion7.get()
    Question8 = entQuestion8.get()



def displayvalues():

    # create a new window
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    # add a title
    window.title("Population Model")
    # make the size of the window
    window.geometry("600x600")
    # set the background of the window
    window.configure(background = "#FFFFFF")
    # title
    lbQuestion = tkinter.Label(window, text = "DISPLAY GENERATION 0 VALUES", fg = "#5855FA", bg = "#FFFFFF", font = "verdana 12 bold")
    # place the widget into the window
    lbQuestion.place(x = 10, y = 10)

    print(Question1.get())
    print(Question2.get())
    print(Question3.get())
    print(Question4.get())
    print(Question5.get())
    print(Question6.get())
    print(Question7.get())
    print(Question8.get())
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  The comments in your code are useless and should be removed, at least for posting here.  If you are taking a class from a professor that requires such nonsense, you have our condolences.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `command` option of a button expects a function, so your code is wrong when you write `command=entQuestion7.get()`, it should be `command=entQuestion7.get`. But even this way, nothing will happend because you don't do anything with the value.

Secondly, I think it should be easier and tidier to make a class instead of a function for your population model:

```
import tkinter

class PopulationModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()

        # question 1
        tkinter.Label(self.window, text="What is the population number of juveniles?").grid(row=0, column=0)

        # create an entry widget for question 1
        self.entQuestion1 = tkinter.Entry(self.window)
        # place the widget into the window
        self.entQuestion1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # default answers
        self.Question1 = ""

        # create a button widget to check answers ############ QUESTION 1 ###############
        tkinter.Button(self.window, text="Set Value", command=self.get_1).grid(row=1, column=1) 

        # create a button widget to display generation 0 values
        tkinter.Button(self.window, text="Display Generation 0 values", 
                       command=self.displayvalues).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def get_1(self):
        """ get answer 1 """
        self.Question1 = self.entQuestion1.get()   

    def displayvalues(self):
        """ display the initial values """
        top = tkinter.Toplevel(self.window)
        tkinter.Label(top, text="DISPLAY GENERATION 0 VALUES").grid(row=0)
        tkinter.Label(top, text="Answer 1: %s" % self.Question1).grid(row=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PopulationModel()
```